# Compare consecutive elements in array and sum same values

Tags: java, arrays

```
public class LoopTest {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        int[] myarr = {12, 12, 12, 8, 15, 15};

        //Boolean array to mark the elements,defaults false 
        boolean[] b = new boolean[myarr.length];

        //Compare Consecutive values and mark them true if equal
        for (int i = 1; i < myarr.length; i++) {
            if (myarr[i - 1] == myarr[i]) {
                b[i - 1] = b[i] = true;
            }
        }
        int sum = 0;

        //Add all the values in myarr with indices marked as equal
        for (int i = 0; i < b.length; i++) {
            if (b[i]) {
                sum += myarr[i];
            }
        }

        System.out.println(sum);


    }
}
```

Output:

> 66

Explanation:

> 12+12+12+15+15

Is there a better/cleaner way to compare values in array and add only  values if they are equal, without using utility methods?

Comment: Isn't having a previous value holder easier/cleaner approach?

Comment: @Nambari Can you please post an answer? I would like to see the approach!

Comment: @Thinkingcap will the identical values in random position like. `[1,2,3,1,2,3,4]`? or always like [1,1,1,2,2,3,3,4]

Comment: @Rod_Algonquin only add if they are consecutive and same, in your first case it should output 0 and 2nd case 13, the array elements could be random  for e.g {5,6,10,10,3,4,4,4,4,7}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can solve this with `linear efficiency`. This program is a little bit cleaner and works in all conditions, checking all the *edge cases*. It results in the correct answer of **66** for your problem. It loops through the array, and checks if each element is consecutive (same as previous element). If so, it adds the element's value onto the sum. Edge cases need to be included to account for the starting elements of each consecutive block, which have to be added to the sum as well.

```
private static int consecutiveCompare(int[] array)
{
    int sum = 0;

    for (int i = 1; i < array.length; i++)
    {
        if (array[i] == array[i-1])
        {
            if (i == 1)
            {
                sum += array[i];
            }
            else if (array[i] != array[i-2])
            {
                sum += array[i];
            }
            sum += array[i];
        }
    }

    return sum;
}
```

Comment: Do you really need  i>0 in outermost if ? Can't you start the for loop with i=1

Comment: @Thinkingcap Sure, I could save a comparison.

Comment: Your solution is simple, with one another redundant comparison `array[i] == array[i-1]`,  it should be `else if (array[i] != array[i - 2])`, You are already checking that condition to begin with!

Answer (score 2):

You could keep a running count of duplicate items and add them to your `sum` when the run ends.

```
int[] myarr = {12, 12, 12, 8, 15, 15};
// assumes > 0 length
int count = 1;
int sum = 0;
for (int i = 1; i < myarr.length; i++) {
    if (myarr[i] == myarr[i - 1]) {
        count++;
    } else {
        if (count > 1) {
            sum += count * myarr[i - 1];
        }
        count = 1;
    }
}
// handle if last elements are duplicates
if (count > 1) {
    sum += count * myarr[myarr.length - 1];
}
System.out.println(sum);
```

Answer (score 1):

The following code will work:

```
public class LoopTest {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int[] myarr = {12, 12, 12, 8, 15, 15};
        int sum = 0;
        int occ = 1;
        for (int i = 1; i < myarr.length; i++) {
            if (myarr[i - 1] == myarr[i]) {
                occ++;
            } else {
                if (occ > 1) {
                    sum += (occ * myarr[i - 1]);
                }
                occ = 1;
            }
            if (i == myarr.length - 1) {
                if (occ > 1) {
                    sum += (occ * myarr[i - 1]);
                }
            }
        }
        System.out.println(sum);
    }
}
```

Comment: Good approach but you don't need the `if(i==myarr.length-1)` inside loop, refer to @MikeKobit answer

Answer (score 0):

Haven't tested all edge cases, here is what I have in my mind:

```
public class LoopTest {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        int[] myarr = {1,1,1,2,2,3,3,4};

        //Boolean array to mark the elements,defaults false 
        boolean[] b = new boolean[myarr.length];

        //Last value tracker.
        int lastVal = myarr[0];
        //Count occurrences in a sequence.
        int cntr = 1;
        //Sum counter.
        int sum = 0;
        //Compare Consecutive values and mark them true if equal
        for (int i = 1; i < myarr.length; i++) {
            if (myarr[i] == lastVal) {
                cntr++;
                //If last sequence mathching.
                if (i == myarr.length-1) {
                     sum += lastVal * cntr;
                }
            } else {
                if (cntr > 1) {
                    sum += lastVal * cntr;
                    //Reset counter. 
                    cntr = 1;
                }
                lastVal = myarr[i];
            }
        }
        System.out.println(sum);
    }
}
```